# XML file present in visual Studio Azure Function Solution Not getting published to Azure

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, publish

I've created an Azure function which reads the data from xml file. In local everything is working fine. When I'm publishing the project to Azure, I'm getting the below error on Azure logs.

Could not find file 'D:\Windows\system32\xxxx.xml

When I checked wwwroot directory on Azure, this file was not available there. Can you please let me know how to publish this xml file to Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set your xml file to "Always copy" in the Copy to Output section:
[image]

To actually read that file within your Function, you need to first get the current Function working directory. This is done by getting the [ExecutionContext](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function#net-languages-c-f-etc), something like this:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "XMLFile1.xml");
}
```

Comment: thank you....it worked and now file is copied to wwwroot folder. But now I'm getting another error.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file 'D:\Windows\system32\xxxx.xml'. Though file is placed at wwwroot folder

Comment: see my addition to my answer

Comment: glad to hear it